# On clicking back button, go to home page if navigating through hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So below I present the navigation scenario for my app:

**Menu after clicking on the Hamburger icon**

- Home
- Profile
- Saved Address
- Wallet
- Logout

None of the above screens are dependent on any of the other screens listed above.

Hence, to navigate I am using navigate.replace(). But as I already know, we cannot pop or go back if we use replace.

What I actually wanna achieve is something like how Gmail android app works. If you navigate using the hamburger menu and hit the back hardware button on android, you go back to the home screen before exiting the app. In my scenario, it directly exits the app.

Below I have presented a small snippet of my work until now:

**app.android.js:**

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  BackAndroid,
  Navigator
} from 'react-native';

import Drawer from 'react-native-drawer';

// Import icon for close button
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

// Import route components
import Home from './customer/home/home';
import Profile from './customer/profile/profile';
import MyOrders from './customer/my_orders/my_orders';
import SavedAddresses from './customer/saved_addresses/saved_addresses';
import Wallet from './customer/wallet/wallet';

// Import nav menu
import Menu from './menu/menu';

/**
 * navigationStyles={Navigator.NavigationBar.StylesIOS} props to Navigator.NavigationBar
 * This will apply iOS styles to android as well. We can also apply android style on iOS devices
 *
*/


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Icons
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Hamburger icon
const hamburgerIcon = <Icon name="bars" size={25} color={'#3d3d3d'} />;

// Cart icon
const cartIcon = <Icon name="shopping-cart" size={25} color={'#3d3d3d'} />;


// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Make routes like the one below to push your screen to the new component
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Home screen
const homeScene = {
  title: 'home',
  component: Home,
  passProps: {
    name: 'home'
  }
};

// Customer profile page
const profile = {
  title: 'profile',
  component: Profile,
  passProps: {
    name: 'profile'
  }
};

// Customer's my order page
const myOrders = {
  title: 'my orders',
  component: MyOrders,
  passProps: {
    name: 'my orders'
  }
};

// Customer's saved address page
const savedAddresses = {
  title: 'saved addresses',
  component: SavedAddresses,
  passProps: {
    name: 'saved addresses'
  }
};

// Customer's saved address page
const wallet = {
  title: 'wallet',
  component: Wallet,
  passProps: {
    name: 'wallet'
  }
};

const logout = {
  title: 'Home',
  component: Home,
  passProps: {
    name: 'logout'
  }
};

const menu = [
  homeScene,
  profile,
  myOrders,
  savedAddresses,
  wallet,
  logout
];

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Android hardware back button functionality
// ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

let _navigator;
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
  if (_navigator && _navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
    _navigator.pop();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
});



/**
 * Class app from where the app bootstraps
 */
export default class App extends Component {

  // This is where all your routes will be processed
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    // Set a variable to get the route
    let RouteComponent = route.component;

    _navigator = navigator;

    // With props return the components
    return <RouteComponent navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps} />;
  }

  static navigationBarRouteMapper = openControlPanel => ({
      LeftButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity style={navBarStyle.left} onPress={() => openControlPanel()}>
            <View>
              {hamburgerIcon}
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      },
      RightButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return (
          <View style={navBarStyle.right}>
            {cartIcon}
            <View style={navBarStyle.counter}>
              <Text style={navBarStyle.counterText}>20</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        );
      },
      Title: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
        return <Text style={navBarStyle.title}>{route.title.toUpperCase()}</Text>;
      }
  })

  closeControlPanel() {
    this._drawer.close();
  }

  openControlPanel() {
    this._drawer.open();
  }

  getNavigator(route) {
    this.refs.navigator.replace(route);
    this.closeControlPanel();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Drawer
        ref={ (ref) => { this._drawer = ref; } }
        type="overlay"
        content={<Menu navigator={this.getNavigator.bind(this)} menuItems={menu} closeControlPanel={this.closeControlPanel.bind(this)} />}
        tapToClose={true}
        openDrawerOffset={0.2}
        panCloseMask={0.2}
        panOpenMask={20}
        acceptPan={true}
        closedDrawerOffset={-3}
        styles={drawerStyle}
        tweenHandler={(ratio) => ({

          // This code will maintain the opacity for main
          // Whilst the opacity for the mainOverlay on the screen will be faded.
          main: { opacity: 1 },
          mainOverlay: {
            opacity: ratio / 2,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
          }

        })}>
        <Navigator
          initialRoute={homeScene}
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          ref="navigator"
          navigationBar={
            <Navigator.NavigationBar
              routeMapper={App.navigationBarRouteMapper(this.openControlPanel.bind(this))}
              style={navBarStyle.navBar}
            />
          }
        />
      </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that, I am only expecting this behaviour (go back to home before exiting), if user navigates using the menu.

**Example, if I navigate to profile and then may be Saved address, then on clicking back, home screen should appear before exiting. Gmail android app is the best example.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution to tackle exiting the app on clicking back when routes are replaced. So, this is how I go to home page before app exits:

```
BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
  if (_navigator && _navigator.getCurrentRoutes().length > 1) {
    _navigator.pop();
    return true;
  } 

  // Check if current route is home on clicking back
  // If not navigate to home else close the app
  else if(_navigator && _navigator.navigationContext._currentRoute.title !== 'home') {
    _navigator.replace(homeScene);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
});
```

This might not be the exact solution but works for me.